# Design limitations

Tags: discussion, design

I've been trying to find the blog post/answer written somewhere on Stack Exchange regarding the design of new website that have passed the beta phased but cannot find it.

Does anyone know the limitations of the design and how much input we (the JSE community) can have on the design of the new site?

Comment: This looks topical: [When will a graduated site get a theme or custom branding?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368463/352329)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything definite either, but [this meta discussion](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/design-for-the-official-wordpress-se-site) from WordPress SE shows some discussion on the site design. However, that was *after* the designer created his proposal, but the designer is absolutely part of the discussion, explaining his thoughts and ideas.